# Proving Fisher's Theorem for Linear Regression

Tags: regression

The model is set up as follows: 
Random variables $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ are given by $Y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i +\epsilon_i$ where $\alpha,\beta,x_1,...,x_n$ are constants with $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$ and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...,\epsilon_n$ are independent random variables each having the Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. Define the random variables $\hat{\alpha} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and $\hat{\beta} = \big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iY_i\big)/\big(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\big)$.

I have found the joint distribution of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ and now need to choose an orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix $A$, with $Z=AY$ so that $$R^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}x_i)^2 = \sum_{i=3}^n Z_i^2$$ Then, using this, I need to compute the joint distribution of $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$ and $R^2/\sigma^2$.

I chose the first row of $A$ to be $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},..., \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ and the second to be $\Big(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{\sum x_j^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{\sum x_j^2}},...,\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{\sum x_j^2}}\Big)$, which yielded the desired equality above for $R^2$. Then I get stuck.

Since $A$ is orthogonal, the entries of $Z$ are independent and identically distributed $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables. This then gives $R^2/\sigma^2$ as being $\chi_{n-2}^2$. But by multiplying out the first row of $A$ with $Y$ we obtain $Z_1=\sqrt{n}\hat{\alpha}$ which has mean $\sqrt{n}\alpha$, not 0. So I get really confused at this point.

I feel like we the answer should be:
$\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$ and $R^2/\sigma^2$ are independent, $\hat{\alpha}$ has $N(\alpha,\sigma^2/n)$ distribution, $\hat{\beta}$ has $N(\beta,\sigma^2/\sum x_j^2)$ and $R^2\sigma^2$ is $\chi_{n-2}^2$.

Comment: I'm not really sure what theorem you are trying to prove. Can you cite it clearly in your question? Sounds a little bit like a Cohran's Theorem to me, but I'm not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: @Wassermann I accidentally asked this question in a guest account somehow and now can’t log in.... Basically I want to find the joint distribution of $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$ and $R^2/\sigma^2$, ie prove the result stated in the last paragraph. I’m so close but am stuck with some computation and I don’t know if I chose $A$ correctly. I don’t know if there is a proper name for this theorem - the lecturer briefly mentioned that it was Fisher’s Theorem for linear regression but it isn’t stated with the exercise.

Comment: Visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.